# How do i store a class in a variable in a constructor

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Hello i'm new to java i'm trying to store a class in a variable and then use ir to set array list type

i was trying to do it like this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyArray
{
    MyArray (class<T> Type)
    {
        ArrayList<Type> Arr = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void ArrSize()
    {
        System.out.println(Arr.size());
    }
    
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyArray Array = new MyArray(class);

        Array.ArrSize();
    }
}
```

Comment: MyArray needs a private field.  The MyArray class declaration needs to define `<T>`.  And you will need to decide what class, exactly, you want your main method to pass to your MyArray constructor.  String.class?  Integer.class?

Answer (score 1):

I may say so, I think you're are not doing the more useful exercice.
Indeed, you try to implement what the ArrayList already do.
You should check how the ArrayList is implemented.

```java
public class ArrayList<E> 
extends AbstractList<E> 
implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

As you can see, the class use the generics.

Moreover, it's a good practice to always use the contract interface to reference an object instead of the implementation.

Example:

```java
List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I know it's just a draft code, but you should always be careful of the semantic used to name the method, class and so on.
In you're code, the method ArrSize should be start by a lower letter and have a more expressive name like printArraySize or something like that.